# Select statistical operations on table without knowing column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am analyzing the data quality of a number of tables in regards to quantitative measures like Min, Max, Average, Standard Deviation etc.

*How do I select different statistical operations (Min, Max, Standard Deviation...) on all table columns **without knowing the table column names**?*

So something like:

> Select min(col1), max(col1), stdev(col1), min(col2)... , min(colN)
>   from table1

But making a dynamic reference to the column names because I have to run this on numerous tables with different column names and I dont want to change code every time.

I am using SQL Management Studio.

Thank you very mcuh

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL to construct the query.  But in general you need the column names to write expressions.

Comment: you could use dynamic sql and a cursor through the sys tables but that could get very messy and take an age to run

Comment: Even if you did get this working with dynamic SQL, due to the differing number of columns in each table, this would return a result set that would be very awkwark to consume. What exactly are u trying to accomplish? There might be a more SQL-y way to achieve it.

Comment: Not to mention you are going to have jump some serious hurdles here. You can't do things like STDEV on many different datatypes.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! I am new to dynamic SQL. Again, what I am trying to accomplish is standard analysis of the values for many columns in many tables and i don't write each column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is one fairly reasonable way to do such a thing:
**Note** You need to add the rest of the numeric data types to this example.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 
'
UNION ALL
SELECT '''+ TABLE_NAME +''' As TableName, 
       '''+ COLUMN_NAME +''' As ColumnName, 
       MIN('+ COLUMN_NAME +') As [Min], 
       MAX('+ COLUMN_NAME +') As [Max], 
       STDEV('+ COLUMN_NAME +') As [STDEV]
FROM '+ TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE DATA_TYPE IN('tinyint', 'smallint', 'int', 'bigint') -- Add other numeric data types 

SELECT @SQL = STUFF(@SQL, 1, 11, '') -- Remove the first `UNION ALL` from the query

EXEC(@SQL)
```

The result of this query will be structured like this:

```
TableName   ColumnName  Min     Max     STDEV
Table1      Col1        -123    543     100
Table1      Col2        54      72      5
Table1      Col3        0       1000    100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zohar! It works but "information_schema.columns" is showing me information/ tables from the "System Database" not the database i am working with. How can I specify the database for "information_schema.columns" ?

Comment: Read about the use statement. You can also do this: `database.information_schema.columns`. Of course you need to replace database with the name of your database.